# Filter state between 2 values and re-render it

Tags: reactjs

I have in my state an array containing some order, and through user input, I would like to filter the orders between 2 numbers: the lowest order id the user wants to see and the highest (most recent). In my state the order number(for the first order) can be accessed by `this.state.orders.orders[0].order_number`.

I wrtoe two function that takes the input of the user and saves it in the state as `filterFrom` and `filterTo`. While the filter values are at 
`{orders: { orders: [], filterFrom: 0, filterTo: 0 }}`

```
updateFromValue(evt) {
    this.setState({
      filterFrom: evt.target.value
    });
  }
  updateToValue(evt) {
    this.setState({
      filterTo: evt.target.value
    });
  }
```

How can I modify the state setting it with the values updated, so that the render methods re-renders some views of those orders?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `filter` function before the `map`,
I'm not sure how are you displaying orders currently so this is an example of how you could achieve that:

```
  isInRange(orderNumber) {
    let isInRange = true;
    if (this.state.filterFrom !== undefined && this.state.filterFrom !== null) {
      isInRange = orderNumber >= this.state.filterFrom;
    }
    if (
      isInRange &&
      this.state.filterTo !== undefined &&
      this.state.filterTo !== null
    ) {
      isInRange = orderNumber <= this.state.filterFrom;
    }
    return isInRange;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.orders.orders
          .filter(
            order => this.isInRange(order.orderNumber)
          )
          .map(filteredOrder => {
            return <div>{filteredOrder.orderNumber}</div>;
          })}
      </div>
    );
```

In the `filter` we check if the `orderNumber` is bigger than `filterFrom` and smaller than `filterTo`, then we `map` over the orders that passed the check on `isInRange` function